# Is there a way to return data from .NET Core AuthorizationHandler Filter?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I am writing a web application in .NET Core 3.0.

When the user sends a request, I would like to "authorise" them, using `IAuthorizationHandler` ([more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.0#authorization-filters))). As part of this method, I create an object with some data regarding the authorization.

In .NET Framework, I was able to return this data with `AuthorizationContext.Controller.ViewData`.

Is this possible in .NET Core 3.0 with `AuthorizationHandlerContext`?

Here is some example code:

```
public class ContextActionFilter : IAuthorizationRequirement, IAuthorizationHandler
{
    public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity != null)
        {
            var username = context.User.Identity.Name;

            var objectToReturn = new ObjectToReturn()
            {
                SomeProperty = GetSomePropertyForUser(username)
            };

            //I need something like this:
            context.HttpContext.ViewData.Add("objectToReturn", objectToReturn);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }
    }
}
```